# Regarding the Gerstenhaber bracket on Hochschild cohomology and Morita equivalence

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, hochschild-cohomology, dg-categories, morita-equivalence

Associated to any $A_\infty$ $k$-algebra $A$ the Hochschild cochain complex $CH^*(A)$ has the structure of a dg-Lie algebra and a dg-algebra which are compatible enough that the cohomology is a Gerstenhaber algebra.

If two $A_\infty$ algebras are Morita equivalent, are their Hochschild cochain complexes isomorphic in (i) the category of $k$-dg-algebras and (ii) the category of $k$-dg-Lie algebras, both up to quasi-isomorphism?  Are they isomorphic in some category that feels both structures together?

Now suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ is a dg-category over a field $k$.  We say that the $k$-dg-algebra $CH^*(\mathcal{C}) = End(id_\mathcal{C})$ is the Hochschild cochain complex.  Does $CH^*(\mathcal{C})$ have a bracket that generalizes the known one in the case that $\mathcal{C}$ is a (derived) category of modules?  If two dg-categories are quasi-equivalent are their Hochschild cochain complexes quasi-isomorphic?

Is there a point of view that clarifies these issues?

Comment: I can't contribute anything solid, but I think the operations you're doing are very similar to taking the E[2]-center of an E[1] algebra in a symmetric category.  Lurie has a long paper on the arxiv about E[k] algebras.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question, but perhaps Keller's paper http://people.math.jussieu.fr/~keller/publ/dih.pdf is what you are looking for.

Comment: Keller's result tells us that if $A$ and $B$ are ($A_\infty$-)quasi-isomorphic then $CH(A)$ and $CH(B)$ are quasi-isomorphic (prehaps even in the $L_\infty$ sens, not only as complexes). 

But what do you mean by two $A_\infty$-algebras to be Morita equivalent. 

For a genuine algebra $A$, the Hochschild complex is (I think) the deformation DGLA for the representation category $A-mod$. So it seems that Morita equivalent algebras will have quasi-isomorphic Hochschild DGLAs. 

Comment: The paper in A. Bergman's comment contains the answer to my question.  Indeed, the Hochschild cochain complex of a small dg category has a B-infinity structure, which is a structure that lies between the structure of a Gerstenhaber algebra and a strong homotopy Gerstenhaber algebra.  According to Keller's paper, if two small dg-categories are Morita equivalent, then their Hochschild cochain complexes are isomorphic in the homotopy category of B-infinity algebras. This implies that their Hochschild cohomologies are isomorphic as Gerstenhaber algebras.

Comment: It is well-known the Hochschild cohomology of a graded commutative algebra has the Gerstenhaber algebra structure. But generally $A_\infty$ algebra is not commuative, is there any reference for the $A_\infty$ case? By the way, what is the product or cup structure to take for $A_\infty$ algebra? Thanks!

Comment: Commutativity is not nevessary. The Hochschild cohomology of any kind of associative algebra (ungraded, graded, DG...) is a Gerstenhaber algebra. The particularity of commutative algebras is that their Hochschild *homology* also has a (shuffle) product.

Comment: Actually, Ian's comment and the various solutions to Deligne's conjecture in this context show that the Hochschild complexes are isomorphic as $E_2$-algebras. The operad $E_2$ is a cofibrant replacement of the operad of chains on the little squares operad.

Comment: ok.. thanks for comments! but $A_\infty$ algebra is still not associative.. and i think the Poisson identity is also need to check

Comment: Jay, there's a whole world of theorems saying that whatever is true for associative algebras and can be stated in the language of homotopy theory is also true for A-infinity algebras.

Comment: i know little about the homotopy theory.. do you have some reference with the statement: hochschild cohomology of a-infinity algebra is a Gerstenhaber algebra? thanks :) @FernandoMuro

Comment: Not me, other authors, but the proof is homotopical. BTW, all the A-infinity algebra business is homotopical.

Comment: @Jay what you want, among many other things, is proven in this very futuristic paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9403055.pdf by Getzler and Jones